# I'm running Ubuntu off a USB stick, where are the files stored and do they transfer from computer to computer with the USB

Tags: usb

I'm running Ubuntu for my first time on my computer off a USB drive. This computer is windows native. While running Ubuntu, where are the files stored, are they stored on the USB? And if so will the files, desktop settings, etc still be there if i were to say reboot on windows and later reboot on Linux or if I took the USB out and booted it on a different PC?

Answer (score 3):

If you created your USB drive with persistent storage, the files are stored in an "overlay filesystem" which resides in the USB stick, in a file called "casper-rw", which is essentially a complete ext4 filesystem containing the files created "on top" of the base installation.

The files will be maintained in the scenarios you mention, *if* you created the USB drive with persistent storage. You can also mount the "casper-rw" file in another Linux computer to retrieve your files.

So the key is to create the USB stick with the persistent storage option.

Comment: You may also use a partition for persistence, makes it easier to share files (although you can loop mount the casper -rw). See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

1. Yes to the "the files [are] stored on the USB" and
2. Yes to the "[they] will be there if [you] were to say reboot on
   windows and later reboot on Linux or if [you] took the USB out and
   booted it on a different PC".

Nevertheless we must consider some things:

First of all, the files will be stored on the USB if the USB has been prepared to save the information on it by:

1. Allowing extra space to save the data for Live sessions
2. Having enough space to save the data if the Ubuntu OS has been
   installed on the USB as an operating system.
3. You care of the place where to save your data and let the software
   know the right place (inside the USB) where to keep your data.
4. You don't simply disconnect the USB while the data is yet unsaved on
   the USB.

If you shut the computer down as if Ubuntu were a hard disk drive installed OS, then the data will stay on the USB and you'll be able to try booting in a different computer and access the data which is tripping inside the USB.

Please note that I say: "try booting in a different computer", because of nobody can say Ubuntu will properly boot on any computer. Remember there are old computers which won't allow you booting from USB and other scenarios in which the USB simply won't boot. So please have that in consideration and make a "Plan B" for the situation. Let's say: Having a bootable Live CD will temporarily fix the issue.

Now, for what is about booting on Windows. You may face some situation in order to reach your precious files inside the USB if you try to access from Windows, because of Windows won't natively support Linux Filesystems (ext2, ext3, ext4, etc.) thus this will force you to install some third party software in order to gain read only or read/write access to the data inside the USB.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A persistent install of Ubuntu will use the first casper-rw file or partition it encounters while booting.

If you have a casper-rw partition on your hard drive and a casper-rw file on your flash drive, the partition on your hard drive will be active when booting the flash drive.

If you have a casper-rw partition on your flash drive and also a casper-rw file on your flash drive the casper-rw partition will become active.

You can take the persistence files and partitions stored on your flash drive with you, you can not take persistence with you if it is stored on your hard drive, (easily).

To make things more complex you can also use persistent partitions and files named home-rw that only store home folder stuff.